# How to set the publisher name to an adobe air application

Tags: apache-flex, air, certificate

I am trying to create my own certificate for a adobe air application, I created one already based on this link: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/devappshtml/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7f74.html

But when I install my application the publisher field is still set with unknown, which is at the end what I am trying to do, I need to set the publisher with one specific value.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You need to buy a code-signing certificate from a company like Verisign orThawte or another Certificate Authority.

Read this [blog](http://blogs.adobe.com/cantrell/archives/2008/03/tips_on_getting.html) by Christian Cantrell for more info on how to get the certificates.

The pages where you can buy the certificate from [Thawte](http://www.thawte.com/code-signing/index.html) and [Verisign](http://www.verisign.com/code-signing/index.html?tid=a_box).

I don't think Thawte allows individuals to buy the certificate, but Verisign does.

Remember, you need to buy the Adobe AIR code signing certificate

Comment: Hi Pranav,

Thanks a lot, I appreciate your help.

Let me ask you a couple of things:

1. do you know why the installer is showing unknown publisher even when I created my certificate?

2. Are you 100% sure that if I buy a certificate from any of those companies, the installer won't pop up this alert (publisher unknown)?

Comment: Unknown Publisher is because you created the certificate yourself...Anyone can do that, right? Hence, the identity is not confirmed. If you buy a code signing certificate, it will not show Unknown. Instead, it will show the name that you applied for the certificate with.

Comment: FYI: For both Thawte and Verisign, the AIR Certificate prices for Organizations AND Individual developers is the same. Thawte goes for **1 year $299, 2 years $549** while Symantec Verisign goes for **1 year $499, 2 years $873, 3 years $1248**. For individuals, this is quite a punch in the teeth!

Comment: That is true, but if you're concerned about customers complaining that your application is from an unverified publisher, then your hands are tied.